# Whistle at/to someone

Tags: prepositions

I was walking down the street when someone suddenly whistled at/to me.

Are both okay? If yes, is there a difference between them? Which one is more natural? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you whistle AT someone, it a quite rude thing to do.

> The workmen whistled at the pretty girl.

It gives the impression of a "wolf whistle" or similar.

If you whistle TO someone, it is (for example) to attract their attention, perhaps someone you know.

> I saw Jon across the street, but he didn't notice me until I whistled to him.